# JSON_EXTRACT no MySQL pelo JAVA não funciona

Tags: java, mysql, json

Olá pessoal tenho um campo no mysql chamado itemvenda do tipo JSON com o seguinte dado:

---

```
{"secao": {"codigo": "114", "descricao": "FRUTAS 1"}, "gondola": "1", "cestaBasica": false, "departamento": {"codigo": "018.001", "descricao": "FRUTAS"}, "vendaSemEstoque": true, "unidadesComerciais": [{"precos": [{"pComissao": 0.0, "precoVenda": 4.58, "margemIdeal": 45.0, "tabelaPreco": {"codigo": 1, "descricao": "TABELA A VISTA"}, "usuarioEdicao": {"nome": "MARINEZ", "codigo": 4}, "comissaoPrincipal": false, "descontoBloqueado": true, "pCustoOperacional": 14.25, "pDescontoPermitido": 0.0, "precoVendaAnterior": 3.98}], "excluido": false, "pesoBruto": 0.0, "cobraFrete": false, "pesoLiquido": 0.0, "codigosBarras": [{"codigoBarras": "121", "codigoBalanca": false, "codigoBarrasPrincipal": false}, {"codigoBarras": "221725855120", "codigoBalanca": false, "codigoBarrasPrincipal": true}], "fatorConversao": {"fator": 1.0, "unidadeMedida": {"codigo": "PC", "descricao": "PACOTE"}}, "pCustoOperacional": 0.0}], "fornecedorEspecifico": {"codigo": null, "nomeRazao": "FRUTAS 1"}}
```

---

Dai faço uma SQL para filtrar as Unidades de Medida desse JSON da seguinte forma:

---

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(ite.itemvenda, "$.unidadesComerciais[*].fatorConversao.unidadeMedida.codigo") 'unidadeMedidaJSON' from item ite
```

---

Quando executo pelo Workbench direto funciona, porém ao executar pela classe java me retorna null, alguém já teve esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal é o seguinte antes não utilizava o JSON e tinha uma função que pegava a String antes de executar e fazia um toLowerCase() e como o json é casesentive estava bugando minhas sqls, mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Comment: Pessoal como faço para marcar como resolvido?